# The direction along which there is no change in value of $f=e^{x^2+xy}$ at point $(3,-2)$ is

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The direction along which there is no change in value of $f=e^{x^2+xy}$ at point $(3,-2)$ is

A. $(-0.6,-0.8) , (0.6,0.8)$

B. $(0.6,-0.8) , (-0.6,0.8)$

C. $(-0.6,-0.8) , (0.6,-0.8)$

D. $(0.6,0.8) , (-0.6,0.8)$

I think i have to use concept of gradient. In this question answer will be negative of gradient. I am not sure

Thanks

Comment: How do the options represent directions?

Comment: The idea is that gradient of a function $f$ at $\vec{a}$ represent the direction in which $f$ increases at the greatest rate (so, if one writes down a contour diagram with each contour representing a level set of $f$, $\nabla f(\vec{a})$ represents the direction from $\vec{a}$ in which the contours are least sparse). Thus, the direction $f$ doesn't change is orthogonal to the vector $\nabla f$. You're looking for a vector $\vec{v}$ such that $\nabla f(\vec{a}) \cdot \vec{v} = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change in a direction $v = (v_x, v_y)^\top$ is given by

$$\langle \operatorname{grad} f , v\rangle$$

So you're looking for

$$\left\langle \operatorname{grad}  e^{x^2+xy}, v\right\rangle = 0$$

Thus

$$\left\langle \left((2x+y)e^{x^2+xy}, xe^{x^2+xy} \right)^\top, v\right\rangle = 0$$

$$\iff (2x+y)e^{x^2+xy}v_x + xe^{x^2+xy}v_y  = 0$$

$$\iff e^{x^2+xy}\left((2x+y)v_x + xv_y\right)  = 0$$

Now insert $x = 3, y = -2$

$$e^{3}\left(4 v_x + 3v_y\right)  = 0$$

$$\iff 4 v_x + 3v_y = 0$$

This is satisfied by $(-0.6,0.8)^\top$ and $(0.6, -0.8)^\top$.

Answer (score 1):

It is $\nabla f=e^{x^2+xy}(2x+y,x).$ So $(\nabla f)(3,-2)=e^3(4,3).$ Now, it is easy to see that $(\nabla f)(3,-2)\perp (-3,4)\parallel (-0.6,0.8).$ This is the direction you are looking for.